# how to execute c code securely

Tags: c, compiler-construction

In this scenario the user will submit his/her C code to my server through a browser.
The code will then be compiled and executed on my server and the output will be sent to the user.

Since the user can submit any code (including Viruses, or other malfunctioning code). I will have to take care of that.

So my question is, how can I secure my server from such code?

Comment: You might find this answer informative: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12462/how-is-a-public-scriptable-site-like-codepad-or-ideone-manages-its-sandboxing/12464#12464

Comment: @ShawnChin: I think that it can be posted as an answer too.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot answer you for windows -- I can tell you for linux.

This is an extremly complex problem. You need to think to:

- quota limit
- process that compiles/executes the code to be runned as an unprivileged user.
- do not allow the process to run more than N seconds
- do not allow process to allocate too much memory

I can say that this is a long-term project that you can not finish correctly in a few weeks.

Comment: how can implement sandboxing?

Comment: The bes way is to find an already written GNU project, and start reading its code source. When you understand it enough, you can modify it to your needs.

Comment: + limit file system access (if not already taken care by running the code as unprivileged user).

Comment: limit disk usage in size for each user. if his process uses an unprivileged user 'U', he must set a quota limit fr user 'U'-- say 500M.

Comment: Also don't forget to set NPROC limit. A simple fork bomb will kill the server.

Comment: There are lots of many other problems, and even for an experimented senior it will take 6 months to have a first stable version.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is perhaps equivalent to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), and probably has no bullet proof answer (think of `asm` in malicious *C* code, forged function pointers, computed goto, buffer overflow trashing the return address, `dlsym` & `dlopen`, etc.).

As mentioned by Shawn in his comment (referring to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12462/how-is-a-public-scriptable-site-like-codepad-or-ideone-manages-its-sandboxing/12464#12464)), you could use sand-boxing techniques. Alinsoar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11502610/841108) shows you the complexity of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Other problem to think to : what rights to allow the guest process: is he allowed to open a socket ? If so , what traffic do you allow him ?

In the case you open a socket, then the problem becomes even more complex, because he can deliver an attack over that socket...

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [ideone API](http://ideone.com/api), some mobile devices software do so ([CodeToGo for example](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/codetogo/id382677229?mt=8))