# What are good ways to make an online Linux console which supports basic commands like mkdir and ls?

Tags: javascript, linux, web

For my project I have to make online linux console which supports basic commands mkdir , ls ,rm etc. It will be used for non-CS guys to get familiar with linux environment without installing it in their machine.It should also store in buffer the commands used recently like the original console.

My future work is to implement gcc/g++ support to actually compile and run the C/C++ programs as we see in online code editors.

I know it requires a lot of web programming. But what should I keep in mind while developing the application from scratch. can java script give a nice solution?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to research some of the other projects that have attempted this, [this one](http://bellard.org/jslinux/) is pretty neat.

Comment: Exactly. This work has already been done (he implemented a relatively simple emulator to run an actual Linux image on).

Answer (score 0):

The words "online Linux console" can be understood in many different ways; you should explain more what you want to achieve. [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624569/841108) refers to emulating an entire PC in your browser and running a small Linux system inside the emulated PC. You could also want that your users are all accessing the same Linux system thru a web interface; then two different users could be able to share something on that Linux server.

You might be interested in making a web interface to some Linux terminal, that is to have your Web users interact with a common Linux system. Then you want a Web Linux terminal. Many (usually AJAX based) solutions exist. You could look for instance into [libonion](http://coralbits.com/staticc/libonion/html/)  which provides an [oterm](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/tree/master/examples/oterm) example doing that.

Don't forget the security issues, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11502583/841108).